# job chain at laravel 5.5 tries to apply onConnection to parameter

Tags: php, laravel, jobs

I'm using Laravel 5.5.34 and when I try:

```
CampaignJob::withChain(
    (new CampaignJob($campaign))
)->dispatch($campaign);
```

At this example, I'm trying to execute the same job two times with the same parameter `($campaign)` and `$campaign` is a Eloquent model.

The first time it works, but second I give an error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::onConnection()

Seems that at some place the parameter $campaign is used as a Job. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong. 
Can someone give me some light?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove parameter `$campaign` from dispatch(), so your code will look like this

```
CampaignJob::withChain(
(new CampaignJob($campaign)))->dispatch();
```